IOS App Freezes After Updating Expired Certificates
I recently encountered an issue with my iOS app after updating my expired development certificates. I have checked my app's code, and there don't seem to be any problems there. However, after I renewed the certificates, my app, which is currently in the testing phase, started freezing.
I've tried the following:
Renewed the expired certificates
Checked the app code for any issues
Despite these steps, my app still freezes during testing. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Are there any additional steps I should take after renewing certificates to ensure the app functions correctly?
I renewed the certificates, I examined all the codes, there is absolutely no problem in the codes because I tried with the installed running application codes, this problem exists in the test phase.

An application hang is nothing do with your certificates. Certificates are for code signing, nothing to do with code execution.  At what point does the app freeze? Have you used the debugger and instruments to try and diagnose the problem?

Most likely changing certs is a red herring. Either you changed Xcode version, or just a recompile made some bug, e.g. race condition (already present in code) just being more frequent.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
